# How do I separate a normal "print" from a "for print"?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Just going to get straight to the point, but when I write a normal "print" after writing a "for print" I only get the letter of the last word. Here is what I wrote

```
print("Animal list:")
animallist = ["cows", "sheep", "pigs", "horses", "chickens", "goats", "ducks"]
for animallist in animallist:
  print (animallist)
```

and when I write this

```
print("Animal list:")
animallist = ["cows", "sheep", "pigs", "horses", "chickens", "goats", "ducks"]
for animallist in animallist:
  print (animallist)
print(animallist[4])
```

It just goes and shows the list and the last letter of the last word.

So what im trying to make is a normal list with "chicken" at the bottom aswell. Im not good with this so Im kinda clueless, would love some help, what im looking for is something that looks like

```
Animal list:
cows
sheep
pigs
horses
chickens
goats
ducks

chickens
```

Comment: Don't use the same variable for the list and an element inside the list. E.g. `for animal in animallist`.

Comment: There is no `for print`.

Comment: I am aware that "for list" isnt a thing, I was refering to the "print" in "for", if that makes sense. Also thanks khel, I wasnt aware I shouldnt use the same variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understand the list and the item in the list:

```
print("Animal list:")
animallist = ["cows", "sheep", "pigs", "horses", "chickens", "goats", "ducks"]
for animal in animallist:
  print (animal)
print(animallist[4])
```

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response, I see what I did incorrectly but quick question, what is the difference with animallist and just animal..?

Comment: I have upvoted and im trying to put this as the answer but not enough time has passed yet, but rest assured I will do it once the time limit is over

Comment: @ZavenZareyan they can't upvote, they don't have the rep. And you shouldn't be pressuring people for that anyway

Comment: @ZavenZareyan you can direct people to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if they indicate it answered their question, but don't demand upvotes

Answer (score 0):

When python run the for loop, it re-assigns the variable `animallist` to each item of the `animallist (class 'list')` ("cows", "sheep", "pigs", etc. which are `class 'str'`), so the variable `animallist` has become `class 'str'`. When the for loop iterates to the last item of the list, which is `"ducks"`, it assigns `animallist` to the value `"ducks"`, so when it runs the `print(animallist[4])`, it will print the 4th index of the string `"ducks"`, which is `s`.

You can see the type of your `animallist` variable has changed here:

```
animallist = ["cows", "sheep", "pigs", "horses", "chickens", "goats", "ducks"]
print(type(animallist))

for animallist in animallist:
    pass

print(type(animallist))
```

Output:

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'str'>
```

So you shouldn't use the same name for the variable in the loop functions and the iterable.